# Dailymotion uploader widget callback

Tags: dailymotion-api

Is it possible to pass a callback url to the **Dailymotion uploader widget** (Webpartner), to be notified after a video upload ?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately it is not possible to pass a callback url to do so in this widget.